# Slider jquery e variavel php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Eu tenho a seguinte pagina:

```
  <?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 0 );
error_reporting(0);

include"conn_imprep.php";  

if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['s_usu_login'])) {
  session_destroy();
  header("Location:logout.php"); exit;
}

$v_define_query = $_POST['v_desc'];
$v_define_loja  = $_POST['loja'];
$v_define_desc  = $_POST['v_descricao'];

if ($v_define_query == 0){
ini_set('display_errors', 0 );
error_reporting(0);
 echo '<script>alert(\'Por favor escolha uma das opções !\');parent.location =\'menu_principal.php\';</script>';

}else {



/* NOMECLATURA:
 1 - Estoque Negativo (c/ notas em trânsito) -------------------------------------- ESTOQUE + TRANSITO < 0
 2 - Itens com notas em trânsito -------------------------------------------------- TRANSITO > 0
 3 - Itens com Pedido em aberto no DC (bancão) ------------------------------------ BANCAO > 0 (com opção de colocar variável)
 4 - Itens com possível Ruptura (Necessidade abaixo Fator) ------------------------ NECESSIDADE - FATOR <=  0
 5 - Itens com possível Ruptura (Estoque abaixo Fator) --------------------------- Estoque / Fator com resultado <= 10% (com opção de colocar variável  %)
 6 - Itens com Pedido de Compra de Fornecedor ------------------------------------- PEDIDO > 0
 7 - Itens com Quantidade de Gôndola ---------------------------------------------- GONDOLA > 0
 8 - Itens zerados com Estoque no Depósito Central -------------------------------- ESTOQUE DC > 0 e ESTOQUE = 0
*/
if ($v_define_query == 1) {
 $sql_retorno = mysql_query("SELECT  
  imp_loja       AS LOJA,
  imp_item       AS ITEM,
  imp_desc       AS DESCRICAO,
  imp_dias_giro  AS DIAS_DE_GIRO,
  imp_nec        AS NECESSIDADE,
  imp_pedido     AS PEDIDO,
  imp_bancao     AS BANCAO,
  imp_romaneio   AS ROMANEIO, 
  imp_transito   AS TRANSITO,
  imp_gondola    AS GONDOLA,
  imp_fator      AS FATOR,
  imp_reposicao  AS REPOSICAO,
  imp_estoque    AS ESTOQUE,
  imp_estoque_dc AS EST_DC,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NEC_FAT,
  (imp_estoque / imp_fator) AS EXT_X_FATOR,
  (imp_estoque + imp_transito) AS ESTTRAN,
  imp_data       AS DATA
  FROM importacao HAVING  LOJA='$v_define_loja' AND ESTTRAN < '0' ORDER BY imp_desc ")or die(mysql_error());

} else if ($v_define_query == 2) {
$sql_retorno = mysql_query("SELECT  
  imp_loja       AS LOJA,
  imp_item       AS ITEM,
  imp_desc       AS DESCRICAO,
  imp_dias_giro  AS DIAS_DE_GIRO,
  imp_nec        AS NECESSIDADE,
  imp_pedido     AS PEDIDO,
  imp_bancao     AS BANCAO,
  imp_romaneio   AS ROMANEIO, 
  imp_transito   AS TRANSITO,
  imp_gondola    AS GONDOLA,
  imp_fator      AS FATOR,
  imp_reposicao  AS REPOSICAO,
  imp_estoque    AS ESTOQUE,
  imp_estoque_dc AS EST_DC,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NEC_FAT,
  (imp_estoque / imp_fator) AS EXT_X_FATOR,
  (imp_estoque + imp_transito) AS ESTTRAN,
  imp_data       AS DATA
  FROM importacao WHERE DATE(imp_data) =  CURDATE() AND imp_loja = '$v_define_loja' AND imp_transito > 0 ORDER BY imp_desc")or die(mysql_error()); 
} else if ($v_define_query == 3) {
$sql_retorno = mysql_query("SELECT  
  imp_loja       AS LOJA,
  imp_item       AS ITEM,
  imp_desc       AS DESCRICAO,
  imp_dias_giro  AS DIAS_DE_GIRO,
  imp_nec        AS NECESSIDADE,
  imp_pedido     AS PEDIDO,
  imp_bancao     AS BANCAO,
  imp_romaneio   AS ROMANEIO, 
  imp_transito   AS TRANSITO,
  imp_gondola    AS GONDOLA,
  imp_fator      AS FATOR,
  imp_reposicao  AS REPOSICAO,
  imp_estoque    AS ESTOQUE,
  imp_estoque_dc AS EST_DC,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NEC_FAT,
  (imp_estoque / imp_fator) AS EXT_X_FATOR,
  (imp_estoque + imp_transito) AS ESTTRAN,
  imp_data       AS DATA
  FROM importacao WHERE DATE(imp_data) =  CURDATE() AND imp_loja = '$v_define_loja' AND imp_bancao > 0 ORDER BY imp_desc")or die(mysql_error()); 
} else if ($v_define_query == 4) {
$sql_retorno = mysql_query("SELECT  
  imp_loja       AS LOJA,
  imp_item       AS ITEM,
  imp_desc       AS DESCRICAO,
  imp_dias_giro  AS DIAS_DE_GIRO,
  imp_nec        AS NECESSIDADE,
  imp_pedido     AS PEDIDO,
  imp_bancao     AS BANCAO,
  imp_romaneio   AS ROMANEIO, 
  imp_transito   AS TRANSITO,
  imp_gondola    AS GONDOLA,
  imp_fator      AS FATOR,
  imp_reposicao  AS REPOSICAO,
  imp_estoque    AS ESTOQUE,
  imp_estoque_dc AS EST_DC,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NEC_FAT,
  (imp_estoque / imp_fator) AS EXT_X_FATOR,
  (imp_estoque + imp_transito) AS ESTTRAN,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NECFAT,
  imp_data       AS DATA
  FROM importacao HAVING DATE(imp_data) =  CURDATE() AND LOJA='$v_define_loja' AND NECFAT <= 0 ORDER BY imp_desc ")or die(mysql_error()); 
} else if ($v_define_query == 5) {
$sql_retorno = mysql_query("SELECT  
  imp_loja       AS LOJA,
  imp_item       AS ITEM,
  imp_desc       AS DESCRICAO,
  imp_dias_giro  AS DIAS_DE_GIRO,
  imp_nec        AS NECESSIDADE,
  imp_pedido     AS PEDIDO,
  imp_bancao     AS BANCAO,
  imp_romaneio   AS ROMANEIO, 
  imp_transito   AS TRANSITO,
  imp_gondola    AS GONDOLA,
  imp_fator      AS FATOR,
  imp_reposicao  AS REPOSICAO,
  imp_estoque    AS ESTOQUE,
  imp_estoque_dc AS EST_DC,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NEC_FAT,
  (imp_estoque / imp_fator)* 100 AS EXT_X_FATOR,
  (imp_estoque + imp_transito) AS ESTTRAN,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NECFAT,
  imp_data       AS DATA
  FROM importacao HAVING DATE(imp_data) =  CURDATE() AND LOJA ='$v_define_loja' AND EXT_X_FATOR > 10 ORDER BY imp_desc")or die(mysql_error()); 
} else if ($v_define_query == 6) {
$sql_retorno = mysql_query("SELECT  
  imp_loja       AS LOJA,
  imp_item       AS ITEM,
  imp_desc       AS DESCRICAO,
  imp_dias_giro  AS DIAS_DE_GIRO,
  imp_nec        AS NECESSIDADE,
  imp_pedido     AS PEDIDO,
  imp_bancao     AS BANCAO,
  imp_romaneio   AS ROMANEIO, 
  imp_transito   AS TRANSITO,
  imp_gondola    AS GONDOLA,
  imp_fator      AS FATOR,
  imp_reposicao  AS REPOSICAO,
  imp_estoque    AS ESTOQUE,
  imp_estoque_dc AS EST_DC,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NEC_FAT,
  (imp_estoque / imp_fator) AS EXT_X_FATOR,
  (imp_estoque + imp_transito) AS ESTTRAN,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NECFAT,
  imp_data       AS DATA
  FROM importacao WHERE DATE(imp_data) =  CURDATE() AND imp_loja = '$v_define_loja' AND imp_pedido > 0 ORDER BY imp_desc ")or die(mysql_error()); 
} else if ($v_define_query == 7) {
$sql_retorno = mysql_query("SELECT  
  imp_loja       AS LOJA,
  imp_item       AS ITEM,
  imp_desc       AS DESCRICAO,
  imp_dias_giro  AS DIAS_DE_GIRO,
  imp_nec        AS NECESSIDADE,
  imp_pedido     AS PEDIDO,
  imp_bancao     AS BANCAO,
  imp_romaneio   AS ROMANEIO, 
  imp_transito   AS TRANSITO,
  imp_gondola    AS GONDOLA,
  imp_fator      AS FATOR,
  imp_reposicao  AS REPOSICAO,
  imp_estoque    AS ESTOQUE,
  imp_estoque_dc AS EST_DC,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NEC_FAT,
  (imp_estoque / imp_fator) AS EXT_X_FATOR,
  (imp_estoque + imp_transito) AS ESTTRAN,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NECFAT,
  imp_data       AS DATA
  FROM importacao WHERE DATE(imp_data) =  CURDATE() AND imp_loja='$v_define_loja' AND imp_gondola > 0 ORDER BY imp_desc  ")or die(mysql_error()); 
} else if ($v_define_query == 8) {
$sql_retorno = mysql_query("  SELECT  
  imp_loja       AS LOJA,
  imp_item       AS ITEM,
  imp_desc       AS DESCRICAO,
  imp_dias_giro  AS DIAS_DE_GIRO,
  imp_nec        AS NECESSIDADE,
  imp_pedido     AS PEDIDO,
  imp_bancao     AS BANCAO,
  imp_romaneio   AS ROMANEIO, 
  imp_transito   AS TRANSITO,
  imp_gondola    AS GONDOLA,
  imp_fator      AS FATOR,
  imp_reposicao  AS REPOSICAO,
  imp_estoque    AS ESTOQUE,
  imp_estoque_dc AS EST_DC,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NEC_FAT,
  (imp_estoque / imp_fator) AS EXT_X_FATOR,
  (imp_estoque + imp_transito) AS ESTTRAN,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NECFAT,
  imp_data       AS DATA
  FROM importacao WHERE DATE(imp_data) =  CURDATE() AND imp_loja='$v_define_loja' AND imp_estoque_dc > 0 AND imp_estoque = 0 ORDER BY imp_desc")or die(mysql_error()); 
}
@session_start();
$v_id_usuario = $_SESSION['s_usu_id'];
$v_login      = $_SESSION['s_usu_login'];
$v_nome       = $_SESSION['s_usu_nome'];
$v_sobrenome  = $_SESSION['s_usu_sobrenome'];
$v_senha      = $_SESSION['s_usu_senha'];
$v_nivel      = $_SESSION['s_usu_setor'];
$v_loja       = $_SESSION['s_usu_loja_id'];

     $query_descricao = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM radios_menu WHERE rm_id='$v_define_query'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_descricao)) {
    $v_descricao_categoria = $row["rm_desc"];
    }

    ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br" xml:lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>#
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/datatables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="includes/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="includes/js/datatables.js">
    </script> 


    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />


<style type="text/css">

.button_example{
 border:1px solid #616261;-webkit-box-shadow: #b4b5b5 7px 7px 7px  ;-moz-box-shadow: #b4b5b5 7px 7px 7px ; box-shadow: #b4b5b5 7px 7px 7px  ; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px;border-radius: 3px;font-size:12px;font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block;text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);font-weight:bold; color: #FFFFFF;
 background-color: #7d7e7d; background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#7d7e7d), to(#080A0D));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d, #080A0D);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d, #080A0D);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d, #080A0D);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d, #080A0D);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #7d7e7d, #080A0D);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#7d7e7d, endColorstr=#080A0D);
}

.button_example:hover{
 border:1px solid #4a4b4a;
 background-color: #646464; background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#646464), to(#1b222d));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #646464, #1b222d);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #646464, #1b222d);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #646464, #1b222d);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #646464, #1b222d);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #646464, #1b222d);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#646464, endColorstr=#1b222d);
}

#tblExport tbody tr{
    border:solid 1px;
    cursor:pointer;
}


#tblExport thead th:nth-child(1){
    width:100px;
}

#tblExport input{
    width:100%;
}

</style>
<script> 
$("#slider").slider({
  change: function(event, ui) {

    $("#result").html(ui.value);

    $.ajax({
      url: "reposicao.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        valueChoice: ui.value
      },
      success: function(result) {
      $("#result").html(result);
    }
           });
  }
});
</script> 
    </head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="reposicao.php"></a>
      <img src="img/logo.png" height="50" width="100">
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      </ul>

      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">LOJA:&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo"00$v_loja ";?></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">USUARIO:&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo"$v_nome $v_sobrenome ";?></a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<li><a href="logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off">&nbsp;SAIR</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <button type='button' class='button_example' onclick="location.href='menu_principal.php'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VOLTAR</button>
       <button type='button' class='button_example' id="btnExport"><span class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;EXPORTAR</button>





<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="result"></div>



  <?php
  $query_frase = mysql_query("SELECT 
 frase_id   AS ID, 
 frase_desc AS DESCRICAO
   FROM frases_sistema ");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_frase)) {
    $v_frase    = $row["DESCRICAO"];
       }


    ?>

<div align="left"><h4><?php echo"$v_frase";?></h4></div><div align="right"><div class="panel-title">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><center><b><?php echo"$v_descricao_categoria"; ?></center></h3></b>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<table id="tblExport" class='table table-hover table-bordered table-responsiv table-striped' align='center'>
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="text" id="txtColuna1"/></th>
      <th><input type="text" id="txtColuna2"/></th>
    </tr> 
     <tr>
        <th align='center'><font size=2>Item</font></th>
        <th align='center'><font size=2>Descricao</font></th>
        <th align='center'><font size=2>Est.DC</font></th>
        <th align='center'><font size=2>Dias de giro</font></th>
        <th align='center'><font size=2>Fator</font></th>
        <th align='center'><font size=2>Estoque</font></th>
        <th align='center'><font size=2>Necessidade</font></th>
        <th align='center'><font size=2>Pedido</font></th>
        <th align='center'><font size=2>Bancao</font></th>
        <th align='center'><font size=2>Romaneio</font></th>
        <th align='center'><font size=2>Transito</font></th>
        <th align='center'><font size=2>Gondula</font></th>
        <th align='center' bgcolor='#00CC00'><font size=2>Reposição</font></th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
  <?php
     echo"<tbody>";   
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_retorno)) {
     echo" <tr>";
        echo"<td align='center'><font size=2> ".$row['ITEM'].          "</font></td>";
        echo"<td><font size=2>".$row['DESCRICAO'].                     "</font></td>";
        echo"<td align='center'><font size=2><b>".$row['EST_DC'].      "</font></b></td>";
        echo"<td align='center'><font size=2><b>".$row['DIAS_DE_GIRO']."</font></b></td>";
        echo"<td align='center'><font size=2><b>".$row['FATOR'].       "</font></b></td>";
        echo"<td align='center'><font size=2><b>".$row['ESTOQUE'].     "</font></b></td>";
        echo"<td align='center'><font size=2><b>".$row['NECESSIDADE']. "</font></b></td>";
        echo"<td align='center'><font size=2><b>".$row['PEDIDO'].      "</font></b></td>";
        echo"<td align='center'><font size=2><b>".$row['BANCAO'].      "</font></b></td>";
        echo"<td align='center'><font size=2><b>".$row['ROMANEIO'].    "</font></b></td>";
        echo"<td align='center'><font size=2><b>".$row['TRANSITO'].    "</font></b></td>";
        echo"<td align='center'><font size=2><b>".$row['GONDOLA'].     "</font></b></td>";
        echo"<td align='center' bgcolor='#00CC00'><font size=2><b>".$row['REPOSICAO'].   "</font></b></td>";
     echo" </tr>";
        }   
  echo"  </tbody>";
 echo" </table>";

?>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="jquery.btechco.excelexport.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.base64.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnExport").click(function () {
            $("#tblExport").btechco_excelexport({
                containerid: "tblExport"
               , datatype: $datatype.Table
               , filename: 'ReposicaoAutomatica'
            });
        });
    });
$(function(){
    $("#tblExport input").keyup(function(){       
        var index = $(this).parent().index();
        var nth = "#tblExport td:nth-child("+(index+1).toString()+")";
        var valor = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
        $("#tblExport tbody tr").show();
        $(nth).each(function(){
            if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(valor) < 0){
                $(this).parent().hide();
            }
        });
    });

    $("#tblExport input").blur(function(){
        $(this).val("");
    });
});


</script>
  </body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Nessa parte:

```
} else if ($v_define_query == 5) {
$sql_retorno = mysql_query("SELECT  
  imp_loja       AS LOJA,
  imp_item       AS ITEM,
  imp_desc       AS DESCRICAO,
  imp_dias_giro  AS DIAS_DE_GIRO,
  imp_nec        AS NECESSIDADE,
  imp_pedido     AS PEDIDO,
  imp_bancao     AS BANCAO,
  imp_romaneio   AS ROMANEIO, 
  imp_transito   AS TRANSITO,
  imp_gondola    AS GONDOLA,
  imp_fator      AS FATOR,
  imp_reposicao  AS REPOSICAO,
  imp_estoque    AS ESTOQUE,
  imp_estoque_dc AS EST_DC,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NEC_FAT,
  (imp_estoque / imp_fator)* 100 AS EXT_X_FATOR,
  (imp_estoque + imp_transito) AS ESTTRAN,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NECFAT,
  imp_data       AS DATA
  FROM importacao HAVING DATE(imp_data) =  CURDATE() AND LOJA ='$v_define_loja' AND EXT_X_FATOR > 10 ORDER BY imp_desc")or die(mysql_error());
```

Onde :  `EXT_X_FATOR > 10`

Ele ta configurado para exibir tudo que for maior que 10, mais para ficar algo que possa ser mais independente para o usuário gostaria de usar o `slider`  do `jquery` ou qualquer outro plugin que seja parecido e que deixe interativo como  `slider` com o php mais nunca usei, e não to sabendo como iniciar, alguém poderia me ajudar como fazer.

[Segue o link do slider jquery](http://jqueryui.com/slider/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#slider").slider({
  change: function(event, ui) {

    $("#result").html(ui.value);

    $.ajax({
      url: "teste.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        valueChoice: ui.value
      },
      success: function(result) {
      $("#result").html(result);
    }
           });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Comment: Em meu post uso o método POST e só tem um valor,ali você esta adicionando minimo e máximo, conseguiria converter da forma que preciso ?

Comment: Eu alterei o código, teste e veja se é isso. Eu sugiro que você de uma estudada nesse código com mais atenção, provavelmente ele vai te ajudar muito.

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta com o meu código todo, porque na verdade eu já dei um POST, e o que quero e alterar o valor de acordo com o slider.

Comment: Sim, onde está valueChoice você vai ter que botar o nome do campo que você está chamando via POST